# How to add a simple notepad window in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I need a notes window in NetBeans to write todos or others things for the program I'm currently working on. any simple text field with save functionality would work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

1 Create empty file (New File -> Other -> Empty File)

2 Drag that file editor window by its tab header on desired place for example next to Navigator tab.